# What difference between metallic reflection and polished/mirror reflection

Tags: optics, optical-materials

At the moment I am studying materials in raytracing (I am writing my own personal project)

I found out that there are several types of reflections.

I read this article from wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_graphics)

But, I'm confused, and don't understand the difference between metallic reflection and polished/mirror reflection.

It's the same thing for me, is it?

Comment: Hmmm, > Metallic objects reflect lights and colors altered by the color of the metallic object itself.

Comment: If you are only interested in the computational aspect of this, a different SE will be better suited. If you want your question answered here, you should rephrase it to highlight the physics of the problem (e.g. why do metals have a color?).

Comment: thank you, I figured out the question a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I realized the difference: the mirror reflects all the light (the mirror has no color, almost), and the metal has a color, and it also reflects objects